# Why does using TypeScript class in JavaScript require `.default`?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a TypeScript class that's part of an npm package. For maintenance, I broke up the class into multiple classes, and I built up the ultimate exported class through inheritance. I don't think this matters to my question, but I figure it's better to disclose this bit of information. I defined the class in `ChildClass.ts` like this:

```
export default ChildClass extends ParentClass{…}
```

Tsc has an `outDir` of "build."
The `package.json` file has a property `"main": "build/ChildClass.js"`

Using both `npm link` and `npm pack` and I can deploy the package and consume it with no problem in a TypeScript demo package. However, if I try to use the package in a JavaScript demo,

```
const ChildClass = require('my-package')
const childClass = new ChildClass()
```

I get the error
 `Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.ts(2351)`

If I change the `new` statement by adding `.default` like so:

`const childClass = new ChildClass.default()`

It works. I figured this out by looking at the compiled Javascript. Having to use `.default`  struck me as an unreasonable thing to expect (the hypothetical) JavaScript consumers of my package to know. I also discovered that if I avoided `export default`  and just used `export` then the package works more predictably, so that's what I did. Now I can use

```
const {ChildClass} = require('my-package')
const childClass = new ChildClass()
```

and the similar syntax

```js
import {ChildClass} from 'my-package'
const childClass = new ChildClass()
```

in typescript.

Still, I would like to know what this magic `.default` property is and why I need it.

Also, all other references I found to this error didn't seem relevant to what I was seeing; I thought documenting this might help someone else that runs across a similar error.

Comment: Because CommonJS (Node's `require()` and `exports`) is not compatible with ES6 default exports. The solution to down-compile but still allow ES6 spec compliant module loaders to work is to emit `__esModule` on the exported value. [Babel does the same thing](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime#useesmodules). IMO just avoid default exports, they aren't very useful and create problems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Background:

The ECMAScript Language Specification [specified](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-exports-static-semantics-exportednames) that the exported name of `export default` is just `"default"`. So you can think about it as an ordinary export named `"default"`.

Compiling a ES6 module to CommonJS only has a *de facto* standard, as the ECMAScript Language Specification never mentioned about it. Currently transpilers (TypeScript and Babel) just put all exports to `module.exports`, where default export becomes not special anymore.

Only when the consumers also understand the above "standard" (e.g. TypeScript, Babel and Webpack), they will transform `import ChildClass from 'my-package` statements to `const ChildClass = require('my-package').default` for you. Of course, Node.js deals with CommonJS and ES6 modules separately, and not doing this.

(Actually it's more complicated because Babel mixed `import DefaultExport from 'some-package'` and `import * as AllExports from 'some-package`, modern module consumers has to try both)

---

#### Solutions:

TypeScript has a [special syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require) `export =` to work with tranditional CommonJS consumers (It's not in JavaScript). If you change your `export default class ChildClass...` to `export = class ChildClass...`, it should work as you expected.